# Laravel save() / create() function not storing requested data from the form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a function that will first store data in a table called 'decision' and the id will be stored in another table called 'survey'. It will first check if the id already existed in the survey table and if it does, the update() method is used however if it doesn't it will use save() function.

When I first tried saving the data, it will only create a new data in 'decision' table with only its id, which then be stored in the 'survey' table but the other requested data are not stored. However when I tried updating it, all other data will only then stored in the 'decision' table.

I think the issue is in the way I implemented save() method but I'm not quite sure. I have also tried using create() method but it returns me an error as shown below:

> "Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\xtims\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 1022"

Here is my code. Any advice?

```
public function updateDecision(AssetSurvey $survey, Request $request){
        $surveyId = $request->id;
        $survey = $survey->newModelQuery()->find($surveyId);
        $surveyDecisionId = $survey->decision_id;

        if($surveyDecisionId){
            $decision = AssetSurveyDecision::where('id', $surveyDecisionId)->first();
        }
        else{
            $decision = new AssetSurveyDecision();
        }

        $decisionData = [
            'asset_decision' =>  $request->input('asset_decision'),
            'rejection_remarks' => $request->input('rejection_remarks'),
            'rejected_by' => $request->input('rejected_by'),
            'rejection_date' => $request->input('rejection_date'),
            'retraction_remarks' => $request->input('retraction_remarks'),
            'retracted_by' => $request->input('retracted_by'),
            'retraction_date' => $request->input('retraction_date')
        ];

        if($surveyDecisionId){
            $decision->update($decisionData);
        }
        else{
            $decision->save($decisionData);
        }
        
        if($decision){
            if($survey){
                $data = [
                    'decision_id' => $decision->id,
                ];
                $survey->update($data);
            }
            return response()->json($survey);
        }
    }
```

This is the dd() result:

```
array:23 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Api\Asset\SurveyController.php:587
  "id" => "26"
  "organization_id" => "1"
  "site_id" => "2"
  "site_name" => "reaaw"
  "client" => array:6 [
    "id" => "2"
    "uuid" => "404b329c-4bce-4785-8d2f-a64d91826916"
    "code" => "DEISD"
    "description" => "Digi Telecommunications Sdn. Bhd."
    "created_at" => "2022-11-14T02:59:14.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-14T02:59:14.000000Z"
  ]
  "primary_client_site_id" => "testttttt"
  "pic" => array:3 [
    "name" => "test"
    "phone" => "0145345345"
    "email" => "test@test.com"
  ]
  "coordinate" => array:2 [
    "longitude" => "14.234234"
    "latitude" => "11.34323"
  ]
  "telco_request_date" => "2023-04-12"
  "tentative_telco_rental_amount" => "231"
  "tentative_telco_rental_rate" => array:2 [
    "description" => "Quarterly"
    "id" => "2"
  ]
  "current_progress_status" => "1"
  "asset_decision" => array:2 [
    "description" => "Rejected by Management"
    "id" => "2"
  ]
  "rejection_remarks" => "test"
  "rejection_date" => "2023-04-15"
  "rejected_by" => "test"
  "isDirty" => "1"
  "hasErrors" => "0"
  "processing" => "0"
  "wasSuccessful" => "0"
  "recentlySuccessful" => "0"
  "__rememberable" => "1"
  "organization_name" => "XPERTS-HQ"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because $request->input('asset_decision') is an array.

You don't pass stored data to save method. You can use save method for creating and updating.

And I also believe that you need to change the order of argument in the updateDecision method. $request should be the first argument instead

```
public function updateDecision(Request $request, AssetSurvey $survey){

    $decision = AssetSurveyDecision::where('id', $survey->decision_id)->firstOrNew();
    $decision->asset_decision = $request->input('asset_decision')['id'];
    $decision->rejection_remarks = $request->input('rejection_remarks');
    $decision->rejected_by = $request->input('rejected_by');
    $decision->rejection_date = $request->input('rejection_date');
    $decision->retraction_remarks = $request->input('retraction_remarks');
    $decision->retracted_by = $request->input('retracted_by');
    $decision->retraction_date = $request->input('retraction_date');

    $decision->save();

    if ($survey->decision_id != $decision->id){
        $survey->decision_id = $decision->id;
        $survey->save();
        
        return response()->json($survey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I realize my code order is a bit messy, i will work on that. I have tried your suggestion but I still get the same error as when i use create() method : "Illuminate\\Database\\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, null given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xtims\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Grammars\\Grammar.php on line 1022"

Comment: Can you dd($request->all()) and show it on your question description?

Comment: I have added it in the description

Comment: You get that error because $request->input('asset_decision') is an array.  I edited my answer. You can learn more about eloquent relationship and do according to @silver's suggestion. It makes your code more professional

Comment: Change the code to $decision->asset_decision = $request->input('asset_decision')['id'];

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and define a proper relationship between your models, It will make your life much easier.

If I'm not mistaken based on your description, Your relationship should be [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

So you `AssetSurveyDecision` model should have a relationship like this

```
public function asset() {
    return $this->hasOne(AssetSurvey::class);
}
```

then your `AssetSurvey` model should have a relationship like this

```
public function decision() {
    return $this->hasOne(AssetSurveyDecision::class); 
}
```

Then all you have to do is use `updateOrCreate` on its related model

```
public function updateDecision(AssetSurvey $survey, Request $request) {

    return $survey->decision()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $survey->decision_id], [
        'asset_decision' =>  request('asset_decision'),
        'rejection_remarks' => request('rejection_remarks'),
        'rejected_by' => request('rejected_by'),
        'rejection_date' => request('rejection_date'),
        'retraction_remarks' => request('retraction_remarks'),
        'retracted_by' => request('retracted_by'),
        'retraction_date' => request('retraction_date')
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Yes I figured I should have used eloquent! Thanks